# how to execute for loop with sed in terminal

Tags: 12.04, gnome-terminal, sed

I want to execute the for loop with sed command, and is getting an error for the same

```
for i in <comma-separated server name list>;do "command";echo $i;done
```

where command=sed '/^$/d' /home/nextag/instance.properties|grep -vc '#'

I'm getting the following error :- `-bash: sed "/^$/d" /home/nextag/instance.properties|grep -vc`#`: No such file or directory
lu1`

What is the correct way to execute this command to get the perfect output

I tried this as well>> `for i in lu1;do 'sed \'/^$/d\' /home/nextag/instance.properties|grep -vc \'#\'';echo $i;done`

Also, can some explain the part `'/^$/d'`in `sed '/^$/d' /home/nextag/instance.properties|grep -vc '#'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.

```
for i in <space-delimited server name list>;
do 
sed '/^$/d' /home/nextag/instance.properties | grep -vc '^\s*#';
echo $i;
done
```

Below line is used to remove all the empty lines.

```
'/^$/d'
```

`grep -vc '^\s*#'` will ignore the lines starting with # and gives the count of other lines.

Hope this helps.

Comment: /^$ and /d both are used together??

Comment: can they be used seperately?? if yes then what do they mean separately?

Comment: Please explain /^$/d i can't find it anywhere

Comment: Vipin, What is the requirement? What do you mean by together and seperately?

Comment: I just want to understand the use of these two symbols /^$ and /d

Comment: Say if test.txt file had more empty line. when you use `sed '/^$/d' test.txt` it will remove all the empty lines and print the non-empty lines.

Comment: ^$ will match empty lines. d is for deleting

Comment: The code you provided as it is won't work - the list of items should be space delimited.

Comment: @MartinOrda yes sir. It wont work. Its just a sample code. You need to specify the right values something like `for i in 1 2 3 4 5`

Comment: @MartinOrda feel free to edit the sample code and help the OP

Comment: @devav2 thanks - just made 2 changes to make that code work.